# What is the real answer to SICP 3.57

Tags: scheme, racket, fibonacci, sicp, lazy-sequences

> **SICP Exercise 3.57**: How many additions are performed when we compute the *n*<sup>th</sup> Fibonacci number using the definition of `fibs` based on the `add-streams` procedure? Show that the number of additions would be exponentially greater if we had implemented `(delay ⟨exp⟩)` simply as `(lambda () ⟨exp⟩)`, without using the optimization provided by the `memo-proc` procedure described in 3.5.1.

There are many solutions online. Most claim that the non-optimized `memo-proc` sequence version of the `fib` sequence is the same as computing the non-memoized regular `fib` function. When tracing additions for the non-optimized `memo-proc` version, I see a different story.

Let A(n) be the number of additions performed for `(stream-ref fibs n)`

- A(0) = 0
- A(1) = 0
- A(2) = 1
- A(3) = 3
- A(4) = 7
- A(5) = 14
- A(6) = 26

When using substitution and the function definitions on the non-optimized (non-memoized stream) I can see exactly what these additions are and why they are occurring but I am having trouble coming up with a good equation to answer the question that it actually is exponential.

The additions traced for A(4), for example, are:

- 1 + 0
- 1 + 0
- 1 + 1
- 1 + 0
- 1 + 1
- 1 + 0
- 2 + 1

Here is some pseudocode to show the substitutions for `(stream-ref fibs 4)`, where '`.`' represents infix `stream-cons` and `{e}` represents promise to execute `e`.

```lisp
(cddddr fibs)
(cddr (add-streams (cdr fibs) fibs))
(cddr (stream-map + (cdr fibs) fibs)))
(cddr ((+ 1 0) . {stream-map + (cddr fibs) (cdr fibs)}))
(cdr (stream-map + (cddr fibs) (cdr fibs)))
(cdr (stream-map + ((+ 1 0) . {stream-map + (cddr fibs (cdr fibs)}) (cdr fibs))
(cdr (+ 1 1) . {stream-map + (stream-map + (cddr fibs) (cdr fibs)) (cddr fibs)})
(stream-map + (stream-map + (cddr fibs) (cdr fibs)) (cddr fibs))
(stream-map + (stream-map + ((+ 1 0) . {stream-map + (cddr fibs) (cdr fibs)}) (cdr fibs)) (cddr fibs)
(stream-map + (stream-map + ((+ 1 0) . {stream-map + (cddr fibs) (cdr fibs)}) (1 . {stream-map + (cdr fibs) fibs)})) (cddr fibs))
(stream-map + ((+ 1 1) . {stream-map + (stream-map + (cddr fibs) (cdr fibs)) (stream-map + (cdr fibs) fibs)}) ((+ 1 0) . {stream-map + (cddr fibs) (cdr fibs)})
(+ 2 1) . {stream-map + (stream-map + (stream-map + (cddr fibs) (cdr fibs)) (stream-map + (cdr fibs) fibs))) (stream-map + (cddr fibs) (cdr fibs))}
```

Here is the actual Racket code:

```lisp
#lang racket
(define-syntax-rule (delay f) (lambda () f))
(define (force f) (f))

(define stream-null? null?)
(define the-empty-stream '())

(define-syntax-rule (cons-stream a b)
  (cons a (delay b)))
(define stream-car car)
(define (stream-cdr stream) (force (cdr stream)))

(define (add-streams s1 s2)
  (define (add x y)
    (begin
      (display "Adding ")
      (display x)
      (display " + ")
      (display y)
      (newline)
      (+ x y)))
  (stream-map add s1 s2))

(define (stream-map proc . argstreams)
  (if (stream-null? (car argstreams))
      the-empty-stream
      (cons-stream
       (apply proc (map stream-car argstreams))
       (apply stream-map
              (cons proc 
                    (map stream-cdr 
                         argstreams))))))

(define (stream-ref s n)
  (if (= n 0)
      (stream-car s)
      (stream-ref (stream-cdr s) (- n 1))))

(define fibs 
  (cons-stream 
   0 (cons-stream
      1 (add-streams 
         (stream-cdr fibs) fibs))))

(stream-ref fibs 4)
```

Most answers online say something like `a(n) = a(n - 1) + a(n - 2) + 1`.
The traced output tells a different story.

Answer (score 2):

[*2021-05-05* Note: this differs dramatically from an earlier, *2019* version of this answer.  The actual result is the same!]

Using some kind of conventional maths notation rather than expressing everything in Scheme as I find that easier for thinking about, the stream of Fibonacci numbers, *`f`*, looks like this:

> *`f = (0, 1, f(0) + f(1), f(1) + f(2), ..., f(n-1) + f(n-2), ...)`*

In this expression I've expanded out the `add-streams` function in the obvious way.

So now, if there is no memoization, it's just a matter of counting to compute the number of additions involved in computing *`f(n)`*.  Well the number of additions is the number of additions in the stream itself  +  the number of additions in the two component streams we're adding.

- the number of additions in the stream itself is *`0`* if *`n <= 1`* otherwise *`n - 1`*, which you can see from just looking at the stream above and counting the '*`+`*' symbols;
- the number of additions in the component streams is *`0`* if *`n <= 1`* (no component streams) else the sum of number of additions to compute *`f(n-1)`* and *`f(n-2)`*.

Or:

> *`a = (0, 0, 1 + a(0) + a(1), 2 + a(1) + a(2), ..., n-1 + a(n-1) + a(n-2), ...)`*

And this is exponential in *`n`* of course.  It's easy to instrument the code to count the number of additions and to write this `a` function to check they agree, which they do.

I find it much harder to reason about the case where *`f`* is memoized (which really means when `force` is memoizing) because there is state hiding in all the dark corners.  But the trick is, I think, to remember that streams get accessed linearly: to compute *`f(n)`* I must already have computed *`f(n-1)`*.  And once that's done, then computing it again is a lookup: there are no additions involved.  So this time *`a`* is

- the number of additions in the stream itself, which is *`0`* if *`n <= 1`* otherwise *`n - 1`* as before;
- plus the number of additions in the component streams, *which is zero* since they've already been computed.

Or:

> *`a = (0, 0, 1, 2, ..., n-1, ...)`*

which is linear in *`n`*, obviously.

---

Below is some Racket code which implements enough of streams to be dangerous, with memoization control over `delay` (called `retard`) and `force` (called `advance`), as well as call-counting support: with this you can easily empirically check the above results.  `fc` computes the `n`th fib and counts calls to `+`, `a` and `b` are the non-memoized and memoized versions of `a` above.

```lisp
#lang racket

;;;; advance and retard are force & delay
;;; memoization can be controlled
;;;

(define advance-memoizes? (make-parameter #t))

(define not-memoized (cons #f #f))

(define-syntax-rule (retard form)
  (let ([memo not-memoized])
    (thunk
     (if (advance-memoizes?)
         (begin
           (when (eq? memo not-memoized)
             (set! memo form))
           memo)
         form))))

(define (advance retarded)
  (retarded))

;;;; mλ is a restricted memoizing λ
;;; Again memoization can be controlled
;;;

(define mλ-memoizes? (make-parameter #t))

(define-syntax-rule (mλ (arg) form)
  (let ([memos (make-hash)])
    (λ (arg)
      (if (mλ-memoizes?)
          (hash-ref! memos arg (thunk form))
          form))))


;;;; Streams
;;; functions are prefixed with s

(define-values (snull snull?)
  (values '() null?))

(define-syntax-rule (scons this that)
  (cons this (retard that)))

(define scar car)

(define (scdr stream)
  (advance (cdr stream)))

(define (sref s n)
  (if (= n 0)
      (scar s)
      (sref (scdr s) (- n 1))))

(define (smap p . streams)
  (let smap* ([ss streams])
    (if (memf snull? ss)
        snull
        (scons
         (apply p (map scar ss))
         (smap* (map scdr ss))))))
                
;;;; Counting function calls
;;;

(define (call/counted f . gs)
  ;; call f with 2 arguments for each function in gs:
  ;; - a function which is equivalent to the element of g
  ;; - and a function which will return the call count of that function.
  ;; Recursive calls to the gs are not counted
  (let cc-loop ([gt gs]
                [fs '()])
    (match gt
      ['() (apply f (reverse fs))]
      [(cons g gtt)
       (let ([gc 0])
         (cc-loop gtt (list*
                       (thunk gc)
                       (λ args
                         (set! gc (+ gc 1))
                         (apply g args))
                       fs)))])))

;;;; Counting fibs
;;;

(define (fc n #:memoize? (memoize? #t))
  ;; Return nth fib and number of calls to +
  (parameterize ([advance-memoizes? memoize?])
    (call/counted
     (λ (+/counted +-count)
       (define fibs
         (scons 0
                (scons 1
                       (smap +/counted (scdr fibs)
                             fibs))))
       (values (sref fibs n)
               (+-count)))
     +)))
            
(define a
  ;; unmemoized count (but this needs to be memoized!)
  (mλ (m)
    (cond
      [(or (= m 0) (= m 1)) 0]
      [(> m 1)
       (+ (- m 1)
          (a (- m 1))
          (a (- m 2)))]
      [else
       (error 'a "negative creep")])))

(define (b m)
  ;; memoized count
  (floor (- m 1)))
```

Comment: Should i draw signal processing diagrams to see this more clearly?

Comment: @nate: I don't know.  I think proper computer-science people must have some approach to dealing with problems like this.  I end up just puzzling it out, making guesses and then seeing if they agree with the actual count, which is horrid.

Comment: First of all thank you for putting the time and thought in for this answer. Unfortunately, coming back all this time later i have to unaccept the answer because there is really no actual proof that your equation is correct. We have simply demonstrated that this seems correct. Therefore SICP 3.57 remains unanswered here. If you or someone else can provide a clear proof of the equation and hopefully signal processing diagrams i will accept the answer. I may go back to this question and try to answer it myself, as it's the only question in SICP i was not able to answer to my satisfaction.

Comment: @nate: If you wanted a proof rather than just the answer you probably should have said that... But obviously my answer is not a proof: it's just the answer.

Comment: Hm. The question is this: "How many additions are performed when we compute the nth Fibonacci number using the definition of fibs based on the add-streams procedure? Show that the number of additions would be exponentially greater if we had implemented (delay <exp>) simply as (lambda () <exp>), without using the optimization provided by the memo-proc procedure described in section 3.5.1.64". Have we shown that the number of additions would be exponentially greater if we have not proven that your equation for A(n) is the correct one?

Comment: No,my answer is the one for when `delay` is not memoized.  I think I've answered the wrong question...

Comment: @nate I'm doing to redo my answer because I think I can see it more easily now.  It will unfortunately be entirely different, so you might want to look at it again then.

Comment: hm, ok. Also everything we have done so far has been about the non-memoized delay, that was SICP 3.57, that was the initial question, and that is what you answered for.